Does Elsevier inform authors (or corresponding author) once they received the payment for Article Publishing Charge (APC) for open access?
I have submitted a manuscript to a fully open access journal in Elsevier and they accepted it after several revision rounds. However, after acceptance I received an invoice and I submitted it to my funding agency and they processed it for payments. However, Elsevier sent me several reminders regarding the payment and when they send the final reminder my funding agency already completed the payment. Therefore, I told Elsevier that payment is already done and they asked me to send some details to locate the payment wire transfer (beneficiary account no, posting date, amount paid...etc). I sent such details along with a letter from my funding agency. However, I did not receive a response thereafter by Elsevier, I mean they did not confirm the receival of our payment or anything but kept silent. Should I be worried or were any of you in similar situations ?

In general, when people want money, they are much more persistent and communicative. I assume if they payment wouldn't have gone through, they would have kept on asking for the money.

Send an e-mail asking for a confirmation that they received the money. Close it with "if I don't receive any news from you on this matter, I will consider the payment issue settled." Ask for a return receipt in your e-mail program.
